# What is the difference between group instance id and member id in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I understand that **group.instance.id** is configured to uniquely identify their consumer instances and it should be assigned by the user in the ConsumerConfig but what is the use of the member.id that is assigned by the broker.However the leader will know the group.instance.id of each consumer.what is the need for member.id then?.

is there any way to see the mapping of member.id - group.instance.id through java? code examples will be welcome

Comment: Did you mean `group.id`? And `broker.id` instead of `member.id` (the docs say nothing about `member.id`)?

Comment: kindly check https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-345%3A+Introduce+static+membership+protocol+to+reduce+consumer+rebalances this doc

Comment: Sure, but if you look at the actual documentation section for broker configs, which is generated from source code, there's no `member.id`